# Strange behaviour when manipulating ListView's item

Tags: android, listview

I want to expend the height of 'layout_quota_info' when user clicks the 'about' imageView, so I set a onclicklistener for the imageview.

However, when user click the about-button in row 1, it also affect other rows as well. It happens only when the list length is longer the screen when I need to scroll down.

I guess the issue is related the recycle of ViewHolder, but I have no clue how to get it fixed... 
please help ....

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    Section section = list.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater
                .inflate(R.layout.list_section_item, null, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_section_name);
        holder.room = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_section_room);
        holder.instructor = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_section_instructor);
        holder.datetime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_section_datetime);
        holder.about = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_section_about);
        holder.quota = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_section_quota);
        holder.avail = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_section_avail);
        holder.enrol = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_section_enrol);
        holder.wait = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_section_wait);
        holder.quota_info = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout_quota_info);
        holder.layout_card = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout_card);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.name.setText(section.name);
    holder.room.setText(section.room);
    holder.quota.setText("Quota\n" + section.quota);
    holder.avail.setText("Avail\n" + section.avail);
    holder.enrol.setText("Enrol\n" + section.enrol);
    holder.wait.setText("Wait\n" + section.wait);
    holder.instructor.setText(section.instructor);
    holder.datetime.setText(section.datetime);
    holder.quota_info.getLayoutParams().height = 1;
    holder.quota_info.requestLayout();
    holder.about.setOnClickListener(new OnSectionMoreClickListener(holder, section){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) getViewHolder();
            Section section = getSection();

                LinearLayout ll = holder.quota_info;
                ResizeAnimation anim = new ResizeAnimation(ll, ll.getWidth(), ll.getHeight(), ll.getWidth(), ll.getHeight() + 165f);
                anim.setDuration(300);
                //anim.setFillAfter(true);
                ll.startAnimation(anim);
                ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }

    });
    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView room;
    TextView instructor;
    TextView datetime;
    TextView avail;
    TextView enrol;
    TextView wait;
    TextView quota;
    ImageView about;
    LinearLayout layout_card;
    LinearLayout quota_info;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exactly like you said. because you have expanded a row, and that row gets recycled/reused when you start scrolling a new row will appear already expended.

What you should do is in your else statement, check the size of the height of the layout and reduce it if needed.

```
else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        if (holder.quota_info.getHeight() > ORIGINAL_SIZE) {
            // Minimize it. no need for animation
        }
    }
```

Comment: it works very well for the rows below ! But that's will make the row that user expanded become unexpanded after scrolling back

Comment: That's true, in that case you'll want to keep track of which rows need to be expanded, and which should be collapsed upon being displayed. A quick way to do it is to add a boolean to your section object, or a secondary array of boolean